# cant redirect to the right path when download via ftp server

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, ftp

Here i have a problem with the `download.php`. I am trying to download file but its not redirecting to the right path where i shared a folder on the ftp server. Its always redirecting to the address where all my `file.php` exist.

Here is my home `download.php`

```
<?php
include 'dbconfig';
include 'ftpconfig.php';
include 'aes.php';

session_start();
    if($_SESSION['user'] and ($_SESSION['nik'])){
    }
    else{ 
       header("location:index.php");
    }

$file = $_GET['id'];
$fileFtp = 'ftp://'.$ftp_user_name.':'.$ftp_user_pass.'@'.$ftp_server.'/'.$file;
$crypt = new aes_encryption();
$fileName = str_replace('.enc','',$fileFtp.$file);
$fileNamee = str_replace('.enc','',$file);

$dekrip = $crypt->decrypt_file($fileFtp.$file, $fileName);
if (!$dekrip) {
echo "Gagal";
}
else {
        echo '<script> window.location.href = '.$fileName,'; </script>';
echo "The file ".$fileNamee." downloaded sucessfully";
} 
?>
```

This is the code on my `home.php` to download

`<td> <a href="download.php=<?php echo $row['file'] ?>" target="_blank">Download</a></td>`

When i click the download, its redirect to where the all `file.php` exist

http://localhost/aes/download.php81208-mklh.pdf.enc

not in the shared folder on ftp server where i set in `F:\ftp`. and all the files is in that folder.

How can i fix that?

Comment: are you even successfully connected to FTP? and you have 2 seperate files here. One for FTP and one for DB. where is `$row['file']` coming from?

Comment: both your FTP and DB code need to be inside the same file. You're probably losing a connection somewhere by having your code in seperate files.

Comment: when upload yes, but when download not successfully,  that `$row['file']` is from the query before, because that is table, am i wrong?

Comment: I tend to say "yes", it looks like it as I also added my comment to my answer. Put both your FTP and DB codes with the link inside the same file. I'm pulling towards that, you're not connected somewhere. Either your FTP, or your DB are not talking to each other.

Comment: oh okey, wait wait, i'l try and check it,

Comment: it's past midnight here. I really need to get some sleep.

Comment: im sorry, here is a daylight , of course you can go bad, you can replay me in the morning, thanks a lot bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing `?id` in your link before the `=` sign:

```
<a href="download.php?id=<?php echo $row['file'] ?>"...
```

Plus, seeing `http://localhost/aes/download.php`

change it to:

```
<a href="/aes/download.php?id=<?php echo $row['file'] ?>"...
```

or

```
<a href="http://localhost/aes/download.php?id=<?php echo $row['file'] ?>"...
```

depending on the file's (download.php) location on your server.

Error reporting should be set to catch and display notices.

Make sure the path is correct and that your database query is correct with no errors, because `$row['file']` suggests it.

**N.B.:** (edit)

Both your FTP and DB code need to be inside the same file. You're probably losing a connection somewhere by having your code in separate files.

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php (FTP)

and use `var_dump();` and `print_r();` and your HTML source as debugging tools.

Also make sure that your database's query in a `while` loop, doesn't end prematurely. Seeing another question of yours, you are using `mysql_`.

I.e.: (notice the semi-colon at the end)

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)); // <<< that terminates it.
{
    $file = $row["file"];
}
```

I have seen this happen before, it's an insight.

Comment: yes thanks, but its still same, still show me :
Object not found!

`The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
Error 404
localhost
Apache/2.4.10 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1i PHP/5.6.3 `

Comment: @John add error reporting to your code http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php see if it yields anything. check your paths and permissions.

Comment: @John Plus, your link suggests that you're using this in conjunction with a database. How is `$row['file']` being populated? am pretty sure it's a path issue here and/or something else.

Comment: i already do that bro, its show me no error, just `Object Not Found` ,  i still cant figure it out why redirect to that path,

Comment: @John a 404 means the actual file.php wasn't found on your server, it has nothing to do with the `$row...` code. I edited my answer above to suggest `<a href="/aes/download.php?id=<?php echo $row['file'] ?>"...` seeing that's where your file is, under the "aes" folder.

Comment: @John btw, the filename itself, is it `81208-mklh.pdf.enc` or `81208-mklh.pdf`?

Comment: oh thanks i didn see you alredy edited your comment up there, the filename is `81208-mklh.pdf.enc` ,

Comment: @John That's great John and you're welcome. Glad to hear it, *cheers*

Answer (score 0):

If you put a header before any HTML that is dumped to the client you will redirect using PHP (server side, so you can send headers):

```
header('Location: http://www.yoursite.com/file_location.php');
```

If you want to do a JavaScript redirect you will use something like (client side, so the page can start loading already):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
window.location = "http://www.yoursite.com/file_location.php"
//-->
</script>
```

Comment: what do you mean? thats in my `home.php` or `download.php` ?

actually i use the code in my `home.php` like this 

`<tr>
        <td><?php echo $no++; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['file'] ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['dekripsi'] ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['type'] ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['size'] ?></td>
        <td> <a href="download.php?id=<?php echo $row['file'] ?>" target="_blank">Download</a></td>
  <td> <a href="hapus.php?action=deldata_home&id=<?php echo $row['id'] ?>">Hapus</a>
  </td>
  </tr>`

Comment: @John Your code looks gross.  open and close your PHP calls as little as possible.

Comment: How do you know if the upload is complete, or not?  When it's complete you can do a JavaScript redirect, but if you are doing a page load you can do a redirect by a PHP header.

Comment: iam sorry but iam newbie on this thing, i just trying step to step part by part  and then combine it.
i still cant understand what you mean up there, where i should change my code, in my home.php or download.php , because those two exist the code to redirect.

Comment: You should change it based upon how you know when it was uploaded.

Comment: yes the upload is complete, and redirect by php header.

Comment: Then you should put it right after the stuff with the $_FILE are handled by the server, but before HTML is sent to the client.

Comment: wait wait i'l try that